# Is there is any difference between Javascript events and React Events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In javascript, we use onclick event and in React we use the onClick event. My question is event provides my React is the same as a javascript event or React handle event differently.

Answer (score 2):

React uses a synthetic event system, which is a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. In most cases, a developer may not notice the differences, but they do exist:

1. React synthetic events work identically across browsers.
2. React event handlers cannot return false to prevent the default behavior.
3. React synthetic events always bubble.
4. Before React 17, React synthetic events cannot be used in an asynchronous way unless e.persist() is called.
5. React’s synthetic event system for videos works the same way as HTML/JavaScript Events.

Answer (score -1):

`onclick` and `onClick` events are the same.

The only difference is the capital of the "C".

**Warning**

`onclick` event is deprecated in javascript. Now, we use `addEventListener` and then `onclick` event inside.

Comment: `onclick` is not depricated - it's perfectly fine to use it on your own element where only  one event listener needs to be registered. if you build some tool/package then you should use `addEventListener`